# Dataframe time series transpose

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A data frame as below, I want to resample them by using 'time', 'cars', and 'flow' and transpose them into columns.

[image]

So I need to:

1. add rows of missing minutes, from 09:00 to 10:00, per minute
2. resample it every 30-minute

The final result should look like:
[image]

There are steps behind and I tried my best but it only ends up with:

```
data = {'time': ["9:17",    "9:17", "9:20", "9:21", "9:22", "9:23", "9:23", "9:25", "9:26", "9:27", "9:36", "9:36"], 
'tempreture': [37.7,    37.12,  37.7,   37.11,  37.9,   37.1,   37.8,   37.2,   37.6,   37.7,   37.1,   37.3],
'cars' : [737,  22, 42, 1,  45, 13, 47, 304,    10, 192,    5,  16],
'flow': ["In","Out","In","Unknown","Out","In","Out","In","Unknown","Out","In","In"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df[['time', 'cars', 'flow']]

idx = pd.date_range("9:00", "10:00", freq="1min")
idx = idx.rename('time')

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)

df = df.pivot(columns='flow').resample('30T').sum()
df = df.reset_index()

df = df.set_index('time')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.stack().T
df["Total"] = df.sum(axis=1)

print (df)


time 2020-10-21 09:00:00 2020-10-21 09:30:00 2020-10-21 10:00:00 Total
flow                   0                   0                   0      
cars                   0                   0                   0     0
```

What's the right way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggregate `sum`, then [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and last convert to one row DataFrame by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose with flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df[['time', 'cars', 'flow']]


df = df.pivot_table(index='time',columns='flow', values='cars', aggfunc='sum')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index + ':00')
idx = pd.date_range("9:00", "10:00", freq="1min", name='time')

df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).resample('30T').sum()
df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df.index = df.index.strftime('%H:%M')
df = df.stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1]}')
print (df)
   09:00 In  09:00 Out  09:00 Unknown  09:00 Total  09:30 In  09:30 Out  \
0    1096.0      306.0           11.0       1413.0      21.0        0.0   

   09:30 Unknown  09:30 Total  10:00 In  10:00 Out  10:00 Unknown  10:00 Total  
0            0.0         21.0       0.0        0.0            0.0          0.0
```

But it seems `reindex` here is not necessary:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='time',columns='flow', values='cars', aggfunc='sum')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index + ':00')

df = df.resample('30T').sum()
df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df.index = df.index.strftime('%H:%M')
df = df.stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1]}')
```

Comment: Good day Sir! unbelievable the thing bother me long and you resolve it in minutes! the world GDP won't grow without helping hands like you. thank you very much! btw, can you recommend me a good Pandas book to read?

Comment: @MarkK - I like modern pandas - [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/tutorials.html#modern-pandas)

Comment: sir! What if I want to include, the count of the number of non-zero cells in the "cars" column, as the new columns? i.e. "09:00 In (count of non-zero)", "09:00 Out (count of non-zero)", "09:00 Unknown (count of non-zero)", "09:00 Total (count of non-zero)" ...Thank you!

Comment: @MarkK - Not sure if understand, do you think use `df['cars'] = df['cars'].ne(0)` before this solution?

Comment: amazing, sir! that's a perfect solution! thanks again!